# Azure App MSA Login, Token Refresh Now Failing

Tags: c#, uwp, azure-web-app-service

After months of working without problems, a couple of Azure Apps I have on different accounts are returning 500 when UWP apps are logging in, refreshing tokens.

Azure Apps are configured for MSA Authentication.

500 response code for calls to /.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback

Any thoughts on what changed? Restart of app, republish from Visual Studio does nothing.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Comment: It turned out to be a blip. MSA or EasyAuth.

Answer (score 0):

> a couple of Azure Apps I have on different accounts are returning 500 when UWP apps are logging in, refreshing tokens.

Per my understanding, firstly you could try to check whether the `Client Id` and `Client Secret` for your Microsoft authentication provider are correct. Otherwise, you could enable diagnostic log for your web app and check the detailed error logs and failed request traces to retrieve more details about this error, For more details, you could refer to this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).